# Многопоточность C++ сильно грузит процессор

Tags: c++, многопоточность, нагрузка

Мне понадобилось отрисовывать кое-что в моей программе на C++ с циклом `while (true)`. Я начал использовать `std::thread` и отсоединял поток с помощью `detach`, но столкнулся с проблемой. По какой-то причине это сильно нагружает процессор. Без отдельного потока моя программа грузит меньше 1% в диспетчере задач, с отсоединенным потоком эта цифра может доходить до 20%. Для пользователей с слабым процессором это критически. Что мне делать?

Comment: 1) не использовать detach 2) приводить [mcve]

Comment: Дайте угадаю: у вас в отдельном потоке бесконечный цикл, который ожидает какой-то эвент?

Comment: Да. Проблема решилась банально добавлением задержки Sleep.